# Finding memory usage of a single class in c++

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, new-operator

I have a class `classX` and would like to know how much how much memory all of the instances of this class use. Every new instance is created using `new classX`

Is there a way to do this without modifying source code (ie using tools like valgrind)?

And what methods can I use to do this by modifying the source code (I can't modify each instance creation, but can modify the class itself). 
The only method I can think of is to overload the new operator (but I don't know how to call the original new operator from there)!

Comment: If `classX` owns (i.e. contains a pointer to) an object of some other class, do you want the memory occupied by that object to count towards the total for the `classX` instance?

Comment: no, I just want (#instances)*(sizeof(classX))

Answer (score 4):

It's quite easy to overload `operator new()` in the class. The global one can be then called using `::` to specify global namespace as in `::operator new()`. Something like this:

```
class ClassX {
public:
    void* operator new( size_t size )
    {
        // whatever logging you want
        return ::operator new( size );
    }
    void operator delete( void* ptr )
    {
        // whatever logging you want
        ::operator delete( ptr );
    }
};
```

Comment: oh, I assumed such a thing would go into infinite loop.
thanx

Comment: @karan: not as long as you remember the colons before the new in the function

Comment: remember void* operator new[](size_t size) and void operator delete[]

Comment: @dmayola There's no requirement to overload those unless they are really needed.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to track space used by objects on the stack, you'd be better off adding your tracking in the constructor and destructor. Something like this should do the job.
Only potential issue is that there may be dynamically allocated members that you need to track too.

```
class Tracked
{
   static int space_used;
   static int space_released;
   Tracked() { space_used += sizeof(Tracked); }
   ~Tracked() { space_released += sizeof(Tracked); }
};

int Tracked::space_used = 0;
int Tracked::space_released = 0;

int main()
{
   {
     Tracked t;
     Tracked * t_ptr = new Tracked();
   }

   std::cout<<"used      :"<< Tracked::space_used <<std::endl;
   std::cout<<"released  :"<< Tracked::space_released <<std::endl;
   std::cout<<"live      :"<< Tracked::space_used - Tracked::space_released <<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this approach only works if your application is single threaded or if the class is constructed/destructed in only a single thread at a time.  (Otherwise, the counts will likely get corrupted due to races between threads to update them.)

Comment: @bobbymcr Agreed, threading makes things uglier, but not much. In that case just protect each count using a mutex, and provide accessor functions that respect those mutexes.